# WinRT URI redirection

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way by which my fallbackURI can redirect the app to a webview(.xaml) in winRT app

```
        LauncherOptions Options = new LauncherOptions();
        Options.FallbackUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///abc.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri,Options);
```

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just place an internal xaml Uri in there.

What you could do it register you app for a protocol activation and put an uri that utilizes your protocol as fallback.

Read more about [protocol activation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670(v=win.10).aspx).

Comment: thanks for the reply...i had read that link, is there a better example or explanation?

Comment: I don't think you will find an example for your case, because actually that's not what the FallbackUri was supposed to do. It's more of a workaround. The links at the bottom of the article suggest a sample and some further readings.